# Javascript property saying undefined

Tags: javascript

I have retrieved some data from a web service, and I am able to print the Object to the console.

```
data.cashiers.forEach(c => {
    console.log('c is ' + c);
    console.log('c.name is ' + c.name);
    $('#sales_entry_cashier').append(new Option(c.name, c.uid));
});
```

And oddly enough, it prints `c` entirely, but refuses to say that `c.name` has a value, like so:

```
c is {"uid":"6a661e7d-61a7-477f-b69c-f328b06819a3","name":"Admin"}      sales.js:87
c.name is undefined                                                     sales.js:88
```

Then, of course, it explodes when it tries to append the name and uid. How can I fix this? Clearly, in the outputted Object, there is c.name, being "Admin" - why can't I access the property?

Comment: Maybe other code is updating the object using a reference. Try to put a `Object.freeze(c)` before the `console.log`. if other part of the code is changing the object it will throw an error.

Comment: @lmarqs — Can't be: The two statements are sequential and synchronous, no other code could be updating it in between them.

Comment: Don’t concatenate strings when logging. `console.log` supports multiple arguments; `console.log("c is", c);` and `console.log("c.name is", c.name)` would perform output formatting for each argument separately. You’ll notice that `c` will be formatted like a string.

Comment: @SebastianSimon An excellent piece of advice I will keep in my back pocket! Thank you!

Comment: you need to parse the object first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that it is an object and not serialized?

Check the type in your response first

```
console.log(typeof c)
```

If it is a string then deserialize it

```
c = JSON.parse(c)
```

Go from there

Edit: Confirmed that it is a string.

```
data.cashiers.forEach(c => {
    c = JSON.parse(c)
    $('#sales_entry_cashier').append(new Option(c.name, c.uid));
});
```

Comment: So you're saying it could just be a String that looks like a JSON object? I'll investigate.

Comment: Yes, I'm 99% sure it is a string, because you are concatenating it to a string and instead of saying `[object Object]` it shows the entire object.

Comment: Wow. You are 100% correct. A shocking result, given the framework, but indeed, I tacked on a "typeof" to the existing line and it said String, so... this is exactly the issue.

Comment: And that's a helpful observation about why it didn't print "object object" instead... I'll keep that in mind. I'm a Java guy stuck doing some front end development which I am much much less experienced at. I appreciate the explanation in addition to the answer.

Comment: No problem! I'll update the solution to be more exact then.

Comment: Indeed, that did solve the problem. I actually changed it slightly so as not to reassign the `c` variable, like so: `data.cashiers.forEach(raw => { let c = JSON.parse(raw);` but the end result is the same.

Comment: @corsiKa Just a slight side note: Most modern browsers will no longer print `[object Object]` in console when trying to log them. They will actually show you the object and its contents. Just saying so you're not confused about the result when you expect it to be different.

Comment: @icecub Yes, that actually is the problem - I've been so used to that happening that it didn't occur to me that when I concatenate that I wouldn't still see the contents!